# Rolling up diagonal NA patterns in dataframe?

Tags: r

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
ID1  ID2  Value1  Value2  Value3  
 0    0      5      NA      NA     
 0    0      NA     2       NA    
 0    0      NA     NA      3
 0    1      1      NA      NA
 0    1      NA      4      NA
 0    1      NA     NA      5
 0    2      3      NA      NA
 0    2      NA      1      NA
 0    2      NA     NA      4  
 1    0      3      NA      NA
 1    0      NA      3      NA
 1    0      NA     NA      8
 1    1      4      NA      NA
 1    1      NA      4      NA
 1    1      NA     NA      9 
 1    2      2      NA      NA
 1    2      NA     3       NA
 1    2      NA     NA      5
 2    0      7      NA      NA
 2    0      NA      2      NA
 2    0      NA     NA      1
```

What would be the most efficient way to rollup the dataframe so that all unique combinations of `ID1` and `ID2` contain a row filled with values as opposed to `NA`?

For example:

`ID1 = 0` and `ID2 = 0` would look like this:

```
0    0      5       2      3
```

`ID1 = 0` and `ID2 = 1` would look like this:

```
0    1      1       4      5
```

And so forth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID1', 'ID2', `unlist` the columns, remove the `NA` elements and convert to `list`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df1)[, as.list(na.omit(unlist(.SD))) , by =.(ID1, ID2)]
setnames(DT, 3:5, names(df1)[3:5])
DT
#   ID1 ID2 Value1 Value2 Value3
#1:   0   0      5      2      3
#2:   0   1      1      4      5
#3:   0   2      3      1      4
#4:   1   0      3      3      8
#5:   1   1      4      4      9
#6:   1   2      2      3      5
#7:   2   0      7      2      1
```

---

Or we can use `melt/dcast`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var=c('ID1', 'ID2'), 
       na.rm=TRUE), ID1+ID2~variable, value.var='value')
```

Comment: thought it does give me some sort of little warning: Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'. Any idea on how to avoid it? Not sure where the length should be placed

Comment: @jimbojones Based on the example provided, I am not getting any warning.  It may happen if you have multiple elements for each group instead of the diagonal elements.  In that case, we need another grouping variable.  It would be better to update with an example that shows the warning.

Comment: aha I fixed the problem. Thanks again for your help @akrun

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)

df1 <- read.table(text="ID1  ID2  Value1  Value2  Value3  
0    0      5      NA      NA     
0    0      NA     2       NA    
0    0      NA     NA      3
0    1      1      NA      NA
0    1      NA      4      NA
0    1      NA     NA      5
0    2      3      NA      NA
0    2      NA      1      NA
0    2      NA     NA      4  
1    0      3      NA      NA
1    0      NA      3      NA
1    0      NA     NA      8
1    1      4      NA      NA
1    1      NA      4      NA
1    1      NA     NA      9 
1    2      2      NA      NA
1    2      NA     3       NA
1    2      NA     NA      5
2    0      7      NA      NA
2    0      NA      2      NA
2    0      NA     NA      1", head=T, as.is=T)

ddply(df1, .(ID1, ID2), function(df){
  return(diag(as.matrix(df[, 3:5])))
})
#   ID1 ID2 V1 V2 V3
# 1   0   0  5  2  3
# 2   0   1  1  4  5
# 3   0   2  3  1  4
# 4   1   0  3  3  8
# 5   1   1  4  4  9
# 6   1   2  2  3  5
# 7   2   0  7  2  1
```